# How do I set approot using APPROOT environment variable in yesod

Tags: haskell, yesod

I would like to set the approot value to the value from the Approot env variable in a yesod project. How do i do this? This is my main function:

> ```
> appRootStatic <- (getEnv "APPROOT")    
> warpEnv $ Piggies pool manager appRootStatic
> ```

The issue is that in approot function I have no way to get to the Piggies constructor as Approot is not an instance of MonadHandler?

> data Piggies = Piggies
>       {
>       connPool    :: ConnectionPool,
>       httpManager:: Manager,
>       staticURL :: String
>       }

```
approot = do
        master <- getYesod
        ApprootMaster master (staticURL master)
```

I had tried ApprootStatic before i tried the ApprootMaster data constructor.

The compiler complains: "No instance for Monad Approot arising from a do statement. So my question is how to stick the value of the APPROOT variable into approot?

Thanks,

Comment: Of course, we can add to the cringe factor: we could use unsafe operations to get the string out of the IO Monad and that seems to work for now. I am sure there must be a better way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is:

1. Add a field to your foundation datatype to contain the `APPROOT` environment variable.
2. Define `approot` in terms of `ApprootMaster`.
3. In your `main` function, read the `APPROOT` environment variable and set the field in your foundation datatype.

The scaffolding does all of this for you automatically.

Comment: I just added this as a chapter in the Yesod book: http://www.yesodweb.com/book/environment-variables